# Distributing candies to children

Tags: combinatorics

part (a) In how many ways can I distribute $6$ identical gummy bears and $6$ identical chocolates to $4$ students, if each student must receive exactly $3$ pieces of candy?

part (b) In how many ways can I distribute $6$ identical gummy bears and $6$ identical chocolates to $4$ students, if each student must receive at least $1$ of each type of candy?

What I've done so far (part a):
There are a total of 12 candies and the type of candy doesn't matter. Since there are $4$ children, there are 12 Choose 4 ways for each student to receive $3$ pieces of candy. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct since we are supposed to use distributions.

For part (b), I tried to use casework to find the number of ways for each type of candy, but I wasn't able to get an answer.

Comment: There are $12$ choose $4$ ways to choose four items from a set of twelve distinct items.  This is not related to the current problem and is not the way to choose how to distribute three items to each.  There are $\binom{12}{3,3,3,3}$ ways to distribute twelve *distinct* pieces of candy to the four students giving three each, however this too is incorrect since the candies are *not* distinct.  You have identical gummies and identical chocolates.  As a hint for a correct approach to (a)... choose how to distribute the gummies so that no student gets more than three gummies...

Comment: Once you've given out the gummies, you can give the students who haven't had enough candy the chocolates.  You can approach similarly for (b).

Comment: Can I give out the gummies by giving eat child 1 the first round, then 2, then 3 until i run out?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are suggesting, but it doesn't sound correct since "first round" and "second round" are surely not important in the end.  The first student having received a gummy then a chocolate then a gummy should count the same as the student having received a gummy then a gummy then a chocolate.  After all, in both scenarios they received two gummies and a chocolate in some order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part A:

Suppose that every student receives at least 1 gummy and at least 1 chocolate.  Therefore, two students receive 2 gummies and 1 chocolate and two students receive 1 gummy and 2 chocolates.  There are ${4}\choose{2}$ $=6$ ways of picking which two students receive 2 gummies and 1 chocolate.

Suppose that every student receives either 3 gummies or 3 chocolates.There are ${4}\choose{2}$ ways of picking which two students receive gummies.

Suppose that three students receive 2 gummies and 1 chocolate, and the remaining student receives 3 chocolates.  There are 4 ways of this distribution.

Suppose that three students receive 1 gummy and 2 chocolates, and the remaining student receives 3 gummies.  There are 4 ways of this distribution.

The only remaining scenario is where each student receives a different number of gummies.  There are $4!=24$ ways of this happening.

Therefore, there are a total of $6+6+4+4+24=44$ ways of distributing candies such that every student receives three candies from a total of six identical gummies and six identical chocolates

Part B:

Every single student receives at least one gummy and at least one chocolate.  We therefore need to distribute an additional two gummies and two chocolates among each of the students.  The number of ways will be the square of the number of ways we can hand out a total of two identical objects to four people.

Let's consider two cases: one where one person receives both objects and one where the two go to different people.  Because we have four people, there are $4$ ways of giving one person both objects.  Additionally, we have ${4}\choose{2}$ ways of picking two people to receive one object each.  There are therefore 10 ways of dividing two identical objects among four people, and 100 ways of distributing two pairs of identical objects among four people

Answer (score 2):

First, "12 Choose 4 ways for each student to receive 3 pieces of candy."

Not at all.  If each piece of candy were distinct there would be ${12\choose 3}$ ways for the first child to choose 3 pieces of candy.  Then there would be ${9\choose 3}$ ways for the second, etc.

or ${12\choose 3,3,3,3} = \frac {12!}{3!3!3!3!}$

But that is not the problem you have.

I think the easier thing to do is to allocate chocolates, and then assign children to them.

Some child must receive at least 2 chocolates.  Putting the chocolate allocations in order from greatest to least, we get

$(3,3,0,0)\\(3,2,1,0)\\(3,1,1,1)\\(2,2,2,0)\\(2,2,1,1)$

are the possible allocations of chocolates.

The gummy bears will be allocated in a complimentary fashion.

Now how to assign children?

How many children receive the same number of chocolates?  That makes the denominator for each case.

Case 1.  $\frac {4!}{2!2!} = 6$

Case 2.  $\frac {4!}{1!1!1!1} = 4! = 24$

Case 3.  $\frac {4!}{1!3!} = 4! = 4$

Case 4.  $\frac {4!}{3!1!} = 4$

Case 5.  $\frac {4!}{2!2!} = 6$

$6+24 +4+ 4 +6 = 44$

Part b) you only have two cases to consider.

Comment: It is possible that for (b) the restriction that each student receives three candies is lifted.  If so, one needs only to repeat the argument above a second time for the gummies and apply multiplication principle.

Comment: @JMoravitz I suppose it comes down to interpretation of the question.  It looked to me like all of the restrictions in part a) applied, with the further restriction that every child received at least one of each type.  However, you are correct, that if the some children receive 4 candies and some only 2, we have some additional cases to consider.

Comment: @DougM: For part A, there is also the distribution $(3,1,1,1)$

Comment: @Moko19 thanks!  I will correct!

Comment: I am reluctant to comment since it is an old question, but you have a typo in the very last part, $6+24+4+4+6=44$.